# Watin taking black Screenshots when RDP is disconnected

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-9, watin, rdp

We are using WatiN - 2.1.0 to take a screenshot when an test fails.when RDP is in disconnected mode on all screenshot's are recorded black(using IE9)

on Server we are running

```
windows server 2008 VM
internet explorer 9
```

The screenshots recorded on test failure are all black.

Comment: Please share the code of screenshot capturing. Also if RDP is connected, were you able to get screenshots without issues?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to take screenshots of disconnected RDP sessions.
RDP uses its own display driver, which doesn't pass draw commands if the session is in a disconnected state.

Instead you could keep the RDP connection open. To allow to minimize the RDP client you may add the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\
```

Add there a new DWORD named "RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized" with the value "2".

Another solution is it to move the session to the console:

> To prevent this, don't use the 'x' to close the remote connection, but use %windir%\system32\tscon.exe 0 /dest:console instead. (That will insure that the screen isn't locked). - Nicolas Voron

References:

- [Terminal session when minimized\disconnected returns a blank screen upon capturing desktop snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493200/terminal-session-when-minimized-disconnected-returns-a-blank-screen-upon-capturi)
- [Capture screen on server desktop session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200341/capture-screen-on-server-desktop-session)

Comment: I get: Could not connect sessionID 0 to sessionname console, Error code 5
Error [5]:Access is denied.