# Remote desktop behavior with 3D3 Device and RDP window minimize

Tags: wpf, directx, remote-desktop, rdp, d3dimage

In our C# WPF we use a 3rd party (unmanaged) library that display a map.
We use the [System.Windows.Interop.D3DImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage(v=vs.110).aspx) class.
The 3rd party library uses Direct3D for the the IntPtr32 surface location property.

When i open a remote desktop from another computer and trying to view the WPF Client, we see the map.
Once the WPF UI Client is up, and I minimize the RDP session or close the RDP i will get exception:

```
Direct3D device is lost
```

From my experience with video streaming applications, When a window is minimized, it is stop rendering the image in order to save bandwitdh.
I guess rdp is acting the same ? Is it configureable ? I wish to continue streaming even if window is minimized.

I know that there are [additional settings in the .RDP file as mentioned here.](http://www.donkz.nl/files/rdpsettings.html)
The directx is set to: redirectdirectx:i:1

**Partial answer so far:**
When RDP client application is connecting to RDP Service, when the window is shown, it is GUI mode, when it is minimized, it is GUI-LESS mode, and the Direct 3D Components are really lost. in order to keep them alive during minimize, a registry key must be turned on ([RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193691/1426106))

Comment: What OS are you running for server / client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this page: http://www.networkautomation.com/urc/knowledgebase/running-interactive-tasks-in-minimized-remote-desktop-windows/4ecdf43e03470/

> Use this key for 1 particular user (use HKLM for all users):
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized
>
> type = DWORD
>
> Values:
>
> 0 = SUPPRESS_WHEN_MINIMIZED_AUTO
>
> 1 = SUPPRESS_WHEN_MINIMIZED_ENABLE
>
> 2 = SUPPRESS_WHEN_MINIMIZED_DISABLED

Comment: Is there a group policy for this `RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized` that can be edited ??   If so, where can I find it?